# Pandas : Assign result of groupby to dataframe to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have the following toy dataframe (the real one has 500k rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size': list('SSMMMLS'),
                   'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 14, 12],
                   'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})

   adult size  weight
0  False    S       8
1  False    S      10
2  False    M      11
3  False    M       1
4  False    M      20
5   True    L      14
6   True    S      12
```

And want to groupby `adult`, select the row for which `weight` is maximal and assign in a new column `size2` the `size` column value.

In other words we want a column size2 with the size value of the line with the max `weight` propagated to the `adult` groupby. So all `adult` = False lines will have value S because adult=False max weight is 20.

```
   adult size size2  weight
0  False    S     S       8
1  False    S     S      10
2  False    M     S      11
3  False    M     S       1
4  False    M     S      20
5   True    L     L      14
6   True    S     L      12
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549596/python-pandas-returning-results-of-groupby-function-back-to-parent-table) but it doesn't work for me

So far I have :

```
df.loc[:, 'size2'] = (df.groupby('adult',as_index=True)['weight','size']
                        .transform(lambda x: x.ix[x['weight'].idxmax()]['size']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). I think first value in `size2` is `M`, because max `weight` is `20`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size': list('SSMMMLS'),
                   'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 14, 12],
                   'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})

print(df)
   adult size  weight
0  False    S       8
1  False    S      10
2  False    M      11
3  False    M       1
4  False    M      20
5   True    L      14
6   True    S      12

print(
    df.groupby('adult') 
       .apply(lambda subf: subf['size'][subf['weight'].idxmax()]).reset_index(name='size2')
    )               
   adult size2
0  False     M
1   True     L

print(
    pd.merge(df, 
             df.groupby('adult')
               .apply(lambda subf: subf['size'][subf['weight'].idxmax()]
                     ).reset_index(name='size2'), on=['adult'])
      )          
   adult size  weight size2
0  False    S       8     M
1  False    S      10     M
2  False    M      11     M
3  False    M       1     M
4  False    M      20     M
5   True    L      14     L
6   True    S      12     L
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `transform` with `loc` and `values`:

```
>>> df["size2"] = df["size"].loc[df.groupby("adult")["weight"].transform("idxmax")].values
>>> df
   adult size  weight size2
0  False    S       8     M
1  False    S      10     M
2  False    M      11     M
3  False    M       1     M
4  False    M      20     M
5   True    L      14     L
6   True    S      12     L
```

---

Step by step, first we find the appropriate indices:

```
>>> df.groupby("adult")["weight"].transform("idxmax")
0    4
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    5
6    5
dtype: int64
```

Then we use these to index into the `size` column with `loc`:

```
>>> df["size"].loc[df.groupby("adult")["weight"].transform("idxmax")]
4    M
4    M
4    M
4    M
4    M
5    L
5    L
Name: size, dtype: object
```

And finally we take `.values` so that the indices don't get in the way when we try to assign:

```
>>> df["size"].loc[df.groupby("adult")["weight"].transform("idxmax")].values
array(['M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'L', 'L'], dtype=object)

>>> df["size2"] = df["size"].loc[df.groupby("adult")["weight"].transform("idxmax")].values

>>> df
   adult size  weight size2
0  False    S       8     M
1  False    S      10     M
2  False    M      11     M
3  False    M       1     M
4  False    M      20     M
5   True    L      14     L
6   True    S      12     L
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a more detailed veresion of the @jazrael answer, with your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size': list('SSMMMLS'),
                   'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 14, 12],
                   'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})
#    adult size  weight
# 0  False    S       8
# 1  False    S      10
# 2  False    M      11
# 3  False    M       1
# 4  False    M      20
# 5   True    L      14
# 6   True    S      12
```

To get size value for the max weight line:

```
def size4max_weight(subf):
    """ Return size value for the max weight line """
    return subf['size'][subf['weight'].idxmax()]
```

A groupby on 'adult' will produce a Serie with False, True as indexes values::

```
>>> size2_col = df.groupby('adult').apply(size4max_weight)
>>> type(size2_col), size2_col.index
(pandas.core.series.Series, Index([False, True], dtype='object', name=u'adult'))
```

With `reset_index` we convert the serie in DataFrame::

```
>>> size2_col = df.groupby('adult').apply(size4max_weight).reset_index(name='size2')
>>> size2_col
   adult size2
0  False     M
1   True     L
>>>
```

`pd.merge` on 'adult' make it:

```
>>> pd.merge(df, size2_col, on=['adult'])
   adult size  weight size2
0  False    S       8     M
1  False    S      10     M
2  False    M      11     M
3  False    M       1     M
4  False    M      20     M
5   True    L      14     L
6   True    S      12     L
```